# Test class not covering method fully?

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

Hi i have a custom controller which clones opportunity with a new currency,clones quote and all its quote line item.A button on Quote page layout does all this.While writing a test class to cover this code,i could not cover certain lines and do not know why.The code is as follows :

CloneOppNewCurrencyController.cls :

```
public with sharing class CloneOppNewCurrencyController {
        public List<DatedConversionRate>lstCurrencies{get;set;}
        public String selectedCurrency{get;set;}
        public List<SelectOption> cTypes{get;set;}
        public boolean flag{get;set;}
        public Date closeDate;
        public String qId{get;set;}
        public Quote qObj{get;set;}
        public Quote qClone{get;set;}
        public Opportunity oppObj;
        public Opportunity oppClone{get;set;}
        public List<QuoteLineItem> lstQuoteLineItems;
        public List<QuoteLineItem> lstClonedQuoteLineItems;
        public QuoteLineItem clonedQuoteLineItem;
        public Double exchangeRate;
        public Map<String,Double>mapExchangeRates;
        public List<PriceBookEntry> pbe; 
        public List<Id>pb;
        public Quote testClone{get;set;}
        public Map<Id,PricebookEntry>mapProIdNpBookEntry;
        public List<Renewed_Entitlement__c> lstRE;
        public List<Quoted_Asset__c> lstQuotedAsset;
        public Renewed_Entitlement__c cloneRE;
        public Quoted_Asset__c cloneQA;
        //Constructor
        public CloneOppNewCurrencyController() {
                pb = new List<Id>();
                lstRE = new List<Renewed_Entitlement__c>();
                lstQuotedAsset = new List<Quoted_Asset__c>();
                lstclonedQuoteLineItems = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
                mapProIdNpBookEntry = new Map<Id,PriceBookEntry>();
                //get quote Id from Page
                qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

                //Get the Opp Id
               qObj=[Select q.Total_Price__c, q.Total_Margin__c, q.Total_Cost__c, q.TotalPrice, q.Tax, q.SystemModstamp, q.Subtotal, 
                            q.Status, q.Siebel_Id__c, q.ShippingStreet, q.ShippingState, q.ShippingPostalCode, q.ShippingName, q.ShippingHandling, 
                            q.ShippingCountry, q.ShippingCity, q.Revision_Number__c, q.Quote_Expiry__c, q.Quote_Date__c, q.QuoteToStreet, 
                            q.QuoteToState, q.QuoteToPostalCode, q.QuoteToName, q.QuoteToCountry, q.QuoteToCity, q.QuoteNumber, q.Pricebook2Id, 
                            q.Price_Book__c, q.Phone, q.Opportunity.Id, q.OpportunityId, q.Name, q.LineItemCount, q.LastModifiedDate, 
                            q.LastModifiedById, q.IsSyncing, q.IsDeleted, q.Internal_Notes__c, q.Id, q.GrandTotal, q.Fax, q.Email, q.Discount, 
                            q.Description, q.Default_Payment_Terms__c, q.Customer_Comments__c, q.CurrencyIsoCode, q.CreatedDate, q.CreatedById, 
                            q.ContactId, q.BillingStreet, q.BillingState, q.BillingPostalCode, q.BillingName, q.BillingCountry, q.BillingCity, q.Opportunity.CloseDate,
                            q.AdditionalStreet, q.AdditionalState, q.AdditionalPostalCode, q.AdditionalName, q.AdditionalCountry, q.AdditionalCity, 
                            q.Account_Number__c, q.Account_Manager__c, q.Account_Manager_Phone__c, q.Account_Manager_Fax__c, q.Account_Manager_Email__c ,
                            q.Pricebook2.Organisation__c, q.Pricebook2.External_Id__c, q.Pricebook2.IsStandard, q.Pricebook2.Description, q.Pricebook2.IsActive,
                            q.Pricebook2.CurrencyIsoCode, q.Pricebook2.Name 
                    From Quote q 
                    where q.Id =:qId];

                closeDate = qObj.Opportunity.CloseDate;
                cTypes=new List<SelectOption>();
                mapExchangeRates =  new Map<String,Double>();
                cTypes.add(new SelectOption('None','None'));
                for(DatedConversionRate d:[Select StartDate, NextStartDate, IsoCode, Id, ConversionRate From DatedConversionRate where StartDate<=:closeDate and NextStartDate >=:closeDate]){
                        cTypes.add(new SelectOption(d.IsoCode,d.IsoCode));
                        mapExchangeRates.put(d.IsoCode,d.ConversionRate);
                }
                //query all fields in Opp which has this quote to clone it
               oppObj = [Select o.X18_Character_Id__c, o.Win_Loss_Reason_Details__c, o.Win_Loss_Cancelled_Reason__c, o.Where_is_A_End__c, 
                                o.Upload_Date_Time__c, o.Type, o.Total_Price__c, o.Total_Margin_in_Account_Currency__c, o.Total_Margin__c, 
                                o.Total_Cost__c, o.Timescale__c, o.Technology_Margin__c, o.SystemModstamp, o.SyncedQuoteId, o.Suspended__c, 
                                o.Start_of_Close_Date_FY__c, o.Start_of_Close_Date_FY_2__c, o.Start_of_Close_Date_FY_1__c, o.StageName, 
                                o.Solution_Type__c, o.Solution_Description__c, o.Signed_SOW_Received__c, o.Siebel_Id__c, o.Service_Start_Date__c, 
                                o.SecureCall_Margin__c, o.Salesforce_Opportunity_Id__c, o.Risk_Level__c, o.Regional_Contact_for_SFOne__c, 
                                o.RecordTypeId, o.RFSDate__c, o.Probability, o.Primary_Competitor__c, o.Pricebook2Id, o.PS_Margin__c, 
                                o.PO_Number__c, o.Owner_Affiliates__c, o.OwnerId, o.Other_Margin__c, o.Organisation__c, 
                                o.OpenAir_Project_Reference__c, o.Number_of_Line_items__c, o.Non_Portfolio__c, o.NextStep, o.Need__c, 
                                o.Name, o.NTT_Service_Family_Name__c, o.Maintenance_Margin__c, o.MSS_Margin__c, o.Lost_to__c, o.LeadSource, 
                                o.Last_Update_Date_of_Phase__c, o.LastModifiedDate, o.LastModifiedById, o.LastActivityDate, o.Large_Deal__c, 
                                o.IsWon, o.IsDeleted, o.IsClosed, o.Id, o.HasOpportunityLineItem, o.Group_Collaborator_s_Name__c, 
                                o.ForecastCategoryName, o.ForecastCategory, o.FiscalYear, o.FiscalQuarter, o.Fiscal, o.ExpectedRevenue, 
                                o.End_Customer__c, o.Description, o.CurrencyIsoCode, o.CreatedDate, o.CreatedById, o.Contract_Term__c, 
                                o.Collaborate_with__c, o.Closed_Won_Status__c, o.Close_Date_this_FY__c, o.Close_Date_Last_FY__c, o.Pricebook2.CurrencyIsoCode,
                                o.CloseDate, o.CampaignId, o.Budget__c, o.Authority__c, o.Approval_Status__c, o.Amount, o.Account_Owner_Id__c, o.Pricebook2.IsActive,
                                o.Pricebook2.Organisation__c, o.Pricebook2.External_Id__c, o.Pricebook2.IsStandard, o.Pricebook2.Description, o.Pricebook2.Name ,
                                o.Account_Currency__c, o.AccountId, o.A_End_or_B_End_or_C_End__c 
                         From Opportunity o 
                         where o.Id =: qObj.OpportunityId];
                lstQuoteLineItems = [Select   q.Vendor_Cost_Name__c, q.UnitPrice, q.Total_Price__c, q.Total_Exchanged_Cost__c, q.Takeover_PPP__c, q.SystemModstamp, 
                                                    q.Subtotal_Price__c, q.Subtotal, q.SortOrder, q.Single_Creation__c, q.Siebel_Id__c, q.Service_Start_Date__c, 
                                                    q.Service_End_Date__c, q.Service_Calendar_Business_Hours__c, q.ServiceDate, q.Requested_Ship_Date__c, q.Renewed_Entitlement__c, 
                                                    q.Renewal_Product__c, q.QuoteId, q.Quantity, q.PricebookEntryId, q.Price__c, q.Organisation__c, q.ListPrice, q.Line_No__c, 
                                                    q.LineNumber, q.LastModifiedDate, q.LastModifiedById, q.IsDeleted, q.Install_Post_Code__c, q.Install_County_State__c, 
                                                    q.Install_Country__c, q.Install_Contact__c, q.Install_City__c, q.Id, q.Exchanged_Cost__c, q.Exchange_Rate__c, 
                                                    q.Discount__c, q.Discount, q.Description, q.Customer_Note__c, q.CurrencyIsoCode, q.CreatedDate, q.CreatedById, 
                                                    q.Covered_Product__c, q.Covered_Asset__c, q.Cost__c, q.Cost_Price_Original__c, q.Cost_Exchange_Date__c, 
                                                    q.Cost_Currency__c, q.Consolidated_Entitlement__c, q.Comments__c, q.Asset_Expires__c, q.Address_2__c, q.Vendor_RRP__c,
                                                    q.PricebookEntry.IsDeleted, q.PricebookEntry.ProductCode, q.PricebookEntry.SystemModstamp, q.PricebookEntry.LastModifiedById, 
                                                    q.PricebookEntry.LastModifiedDate, q.PricebookEntry.CreatedById, q.PricebookEntry.CreatedDate, q.PricebookEntry.UseStandardPrice, 
                                                    q.PricebookEntry.IsActive, q.PricebookEntry.UnitPrice, q.PricebookEntry.CurrencyIsoCode, q.PricebookEntry.Product2Id, 
                                                    q.PricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id, q.PricebookEntry.Name, q.PricebookEntry.Id,
                                                    q.Address_1__c From QuoteLineItem q
                                                    where q.QuoteId =:qObj.Id];
                 for(QuoteLineItem oLineItem : lstQuoteLineItems) {
                    pb.add(oLineItem.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);
                }
                //query renewal entitlements under the query to clone it
                lstRE = [Select r.Quote__c, r.Quote_Status__c, r.Quote_Line_Item__c, r.Opportunity__c, r.Name, r.Id, r.Entitlement__c, 
                             r.Entitlement_Start_Date__c, r.Entitlement_Service_Calendar__c, r.Entitlement_Part_Code__c, r.Entitlement_End_Date__c, 
                             r.CurrencyIsoCode 
                             From Renewed_Entitlement__c r
                             where r.Quote__c =:qId ];
               //query quoted assets under the query to clone it
               lstQuotedAsset = [Select q.Quote__c, q.Name, q.Id, q.CurrencyIsoCode, q.Asset__c 
                                 From Quoted_Asset__c q
                                 where q.Quote__c =:qId];
        }
        public void proceed() {
            try {
                if(selectedCurrency == 'None' || selectedCurrency == '') {
                    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Please select a currency in order to proceed')); 
                }
                pbe = [Select p.UnitPrice, p.Product2Id, p.Pricebook2Id, p.Name, p.IsActive, p.Id, p.CurrencyIsoCode From PricebookEntry p
                           where p.CurrencyIsoCode =:selectedCurrency and p.Pricebook2Id =:oppObj.Pricebook2Id and p.Product2Id in :pb];
                    for(PricebookEntry pbe : pbe) {
                        mapProIdNpBookEntry.put(pbe.Product2Id,pbe);
                    }               

                for(QuoteLineItem oLine:lstQuoteLineItems) {
                    if(!mapProIdNpBookEntry.containsKey(oLine.PricebookEntry.Product2Id)) {
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No pricebook entry exists for this particular currency.Hence kindly create an entry with the selected currency before cloning Opportunity.')); 
                        return;
                    }
                }   

               if(selectedCurrency!='None') {
                if(oppObj.StageName!='Qualification') {
                    oppClone = oppObj.clone(false,true);
                    oppClone.ForecastCategoryName = 'Omitted';
                    oppClone.CurrencyIsoCode = selectedCurrency;
                    System.debug('Pricebook2Id::::' +oppClone.Pricebook2Id);
                    oppClone.Pricebook2Id = oppObj.Pricebook2Id;
                    oppClone.Name = selectedCurrency + oppObj.Name;
                    Database.insert(oppClone);
                    System.debug('Inserted Opp Currency >>> ' + oppClone.CurrencyIsoCode);
                    if(qObj.IsSyncing != true) {
                        qClone = qObj.clone();
                        qClone.Name = selectedCurrency + qObj.Name;
                        qClone.OpportunityId = oppClone.Id;
                        Database.insert(qClone);
                        System.debug('Inserted Quote Currency >>> ' + qClone.CurrencyIsoCode);
                        testClone= [SELECT Id, CurrencyIsoCode FROM Quote WHERE ID=:qClone.Id];
                        oppClone.SyncedQuoteId = qClone.Id;
                    }
                    else {
                        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Synced Quote cannot be cloned.Please stop sync before cloning')); 
                    }
                    Database.update(oppClone);
                    System.debug('Inserted Quote Currency >>> ' + testClone.CurrencyIsoCode);
                } 
                if((lstRE!=null || !(lstRE.isEmpty())) && qClone.Id !=null) {
                    for(Renewed_Entitlement__c re:lstRE) {
                        cloneRE = new Renewed_Entitlement__c();
                        cloneRE = re.clone();
                        cloneRE.Quote__c = qClone.Id;
                        Database.insert(cloneRE);
                    }
                }
                if((lstQuotedAsset!=null || !(lstQuotedAsset.isEmpty())) && qClone.Id !=null) {
                    for(Quoted_Asset__c qa:lstQuotedAsset) {
                        cloneQA = new Quoted_Asset__c();
                        cloneQA = qa.clone();
                        cloneQA.Quote__c = qClone.Id;
                        Database.insert(cloneQA);
                    }
                }
                System.debug('^^^aaa^^^^^^^^'+mapProIdNpBookEntry);
                    if(qClone!=null) {
                        if(lstQuoteLineItems!=null) { System.debug('not null line items');//tbd
                            for(QuoteLineItem oLine:lstQuoteLineItems) {
                                clonedQuoteLineItem = new QuoteLineItem();
                                clonedQuoteLineItem = oLine.clone();
                                system.debug('^^12111111' + oLine.PricebookEntry.Product2Id);
                                if(mapProIdNpBookEntry.containsKey(oLine.PricebookEntry.Product2Id)) {
                                    clonedQuoteLineItem.PricebookEntryId=mapProIdNpBookEntry.get(oLine.PricebookEntry.Product2Id).Id;
                                }
                                clonedQuoteLineItem.QuoteId = qClone.Id;
                                System.debug('Quote line Iso Code'+clonedQuoteLineItem.CurrencyIsoCode);
                                //update price,margin and vendors
                                if(mapExchangeRates.containsKey(selectedCurrency)) { System.debug('$$$containsKey iruku$$$'+'###value is###'+mapExchangeRates.get(selectedCurrency));
                                    if(oLine.Price__c!=null && mapExchangeRates.get(selectedCurrency)!=0) {    
                                        clonedQuoteLineItem.Price__c = oLine.Price__c / mapExchangeRates.get(clonedQuoteLineItem.CurrencyIsoCode);
                                    }
                                    if(oLine.UnitPrice != null && mapExchangeRates.get(selectedCurrency)!=0) {     
                                        clonedQuoteLineItem.UnitPrice = oLine.UnitPrice / mapExchangeRates.get(clonedQuoteLineItem.CurrencyIsoCode);
                                    }
                                    if(oLine.Vendor_RRP__c != null && mapExchangeRates.get(selectedCurrency)!=0) {    
                                        clonedQuoteLineItem.Vendor_RRP__c = oLine.Vendor_RRP__c / mapExchangeRates.get(clonedQuoteLineItem.CurrencyIsoCode);
                                    }
                                }
                                lstclonedQuoteLineItems.add(clonedQuoteLineItem);
                            }
                            System.debug(' >>> ' + lstclonedQuoteLineItems);
                            if(lstclonedQuoteLineItems.size()>0) {
                                insert lstclonedQuoteLineItems;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
        public pageReference cancel() {
            return null;
        }
}

    testCloneNewCurrencyController.cls

    @isTest(SeeALLData=true)
    private class testCloneNewCurrencyController {

        static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
            // TO DO: implement unit test
            Account account=new Account(Name='Test');
            insert account;
            Contact cn=new Contact(Accountid=account.id);
            cn.LastName='test';
            insert cn;

            // set up opportunity name and price book id
            String opportunityName = 'My Opportunity';
            String standardPriceBookId = '';

            PriceBook2 pb2Standard = [select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
            standardPriceBookId = pb2Standard.Id;

            // set up opp and Verify that the results are as expected.
            Opportunity o = new Opportunity(AccountId=account.Id, Name=opportunityName, 
                                                    StageName='Prospecting', CloseDate=Date.today(),Contract_Term__c = 6);
            insert o;
            Opportunity opp = [SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :o.Id];
            System.assertEquals(opportunityName, opp.Name);

            // set up product2 and Verify that the results are as expected.
            Product2 p2 = new Product2(Name='Test Product',isActive=true,Product_Code_Upload__c = 'Test Product 1' , ProductCode = 'Test Product 1');
            insert p2;
            Product2 p2ex = [SELECT Name FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :p2.Id];
            System.assertEquals('Test Product', p2ex.Name);

            // set up PricebookEntry and Verify that the results are as expected.
            PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id=standardPriceBookId, Product2Id=p2.Id, UnitPrice=99, isActive=true );
            insert pbe;
            PricebookEntry pbeex = [SELECT Pricebook2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Id = :pbe.Id];
            System.assertEquals(standardPriceBookId, pbeex.Pricebook2Id);

            // set up OpportunityLineItem and Verify that the results are as expected.
            OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id, OpportunityId=o.Id, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=99 , Cost_Currency__c = 'USD',Cost__c=2000);
            insert oli;
            OpportunityLineItem oliex = [SELECT PriceBookEntryId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = :oli.Id];
            oli.Cost_Currency__C = 'GBP';
            update oli;
            update account;        

            Quote quot1 = new Quote(Name='Quote1',OpportunityId=o.Id,Pricebook2Id=standardPriceBookId);
            insert quot1;       
            // set up OpportunityLineItem and Verify that the results are as expected.
            QuoteLineItem qli = new QuoteLineItem(QuoteId = quot1.Id,PriceBookEntryId=pbe.Id,UnitPrice=1000, Quantity=1, Price__c=3500 , Cost_Currency__c = 'USD',Cost__c=2000);
            insert qli;
            // Create two Asset records and relate them to the oli through Ordered Asset records
            Asset ass1 = new Asset(Name='Asset1',SerialNumber='12345',AccountId=account.Id,ContactId=cn.Id);
            insert ass1;
            Asset ass2 = new Asset(Name='Asset1',SerialNumber='678910',AccountId=account.Id,ContactId=cn.Id);
            insert ass2;
            Quoted_Asset__c ordass1 = new Quoted_Asset__c(Asset__c=ass1.Id,Quote_Line_Item__c=qli.Id,Quote__c=quot1.Id);
            insert ordass1;
            Quoted_Asset__c ordass2 = new Quoted_Asset__c(Asset__c=ass2.Id,Quote_Line_Item__c=qli.Id,Quote__c=quot1.Id);
            insert ordass2;
            // Check that the Serial numbers field on the QLI is as expected
            QuoteLineItem quot1test = [SELECT LineNumber, Serial_Numbers__c FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE Id =: qli.Id];
            Test.startTest();
            Test.setCurrentPage(new Pagereference('/apex/CloneOppNewCurrency?id='+quot1.Id));
            CloneOppNewCurrencyController c = new CloneOppNewCurrencyController();
            c.selectedCurrency = 'USD';
            system.assertEquals(c.selectedCurrency, 'USD');
            //c.qObj = quot1;
            c.proceed();
            c.selectedCurrency = 'USD';
            System.debug('%%%%%'+c.oppClone+'$$$$$'+c.selectedCurrency+'Opp OBj is:'+c.oppObj);
            Test.setCurrentPage(new Pagereference('/apex/CloneOppNewCurrency?id='+quot1.Id));
            CloneOppNewCurrencyController c1 = new CloneOppNewCurrencyController();
            c1.selectedCurrency = 'None';
            Pagereference pr = c1.cancel();
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
```

Lines from 127 are not covered.The proceed method is not covered.Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

What line does 127 correspond to in your example? Is it `if(selectedCurrency!='None') {` in the proceed() method?

I'd suggest to extend your exception handling. You basically have:

```
public void proceed() {
    try {
        // Most of method body here
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

It is likely that an exception has occured and has been ignored/lost due to the empty Exception handling. Minimally, write the exception out to the log:

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.Error, 'BANG! ' + e);         
}
```

That may well reveal in the debug log where your test method is failing.